# Why do parallel plates create a unifrom field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

Uniform fields are created by setting up a potential difference between two conducting plates placed at distance (d) from one another:

The electric field equation is:

$\vec{E}=kQ/r^2$

so if you have 2 plates(+,-) with distance d. then the electric field should be:

$\vec{E_{tot}}=\vec{E_{+}}+\vec{E_{-}}$

$\vec{E_{+}}= k(Q)/(d)^2$

$\vec{E_{-}}= k(-Q)/(1-d)^2$

$\vec{E_{tot}}=k(Q)/(d)^2 + k(-Q)/(1-d)^2 $

but isn't this field proportional to:

$\frac{1}{d^2} +\frac{1}{1-d^2} $

which is not a constant? 
I imagine the filed to be stronger near the plates and weakest in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is electric field of an infinite plate constant at all points?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431247/)

Comment: In line with Emilio's answer, I would highly suggest you understand what your equations describe before your start using them. Blind application of equations rarely works well in physics.

Comment: How would i go from the basic equation of a point charge, to something that describes parallel plates?

Comment: Please look at the duplicate answer I have linked to, or, for an easier way, use [Gauss's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html).

Comment: thanks, i think it is a duplicate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The electric field equation is:
>
> $\vec{E}=kQ/r^2$

... for a point charge or a spherically-symmetric distribution. The charge distribution on a pair of parallel plates does not fall in that category, so that expression for the electric field does not apply.

> Ok, but I am imagining a parallel plate as the summation over many of these charges? does this relationship break down because the dependence on r changes?

Yes, it does change. You are right that the electric field is due to a sum over a whole bunch of individual charges, and that the electric field of each of those individual (infinitesimal) bits of charge will be Coulombic.

(On the other hand, your proposed dependence, $\vec{E}=kQ/r^2$, is obviously nonsense - it has a vector on the left and a scalar on the right. The correct version is $\vec{E}=kQ\vec r/r^3 = kQ\hat r/r^2$. The difference obviously matters.)

With that in place, the electric field of a flat plate with surface charge density $\sigma$ is given by the integral
$$
\vec E(\vec r) = k\sigma \iint \frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|^3} \mathrm dx'\mathrm dy'.
$$
Note that you have a bunch of different distances, and that many of the different chunks of charge exert fields in different directions which partly cancel out with each other. Any expectation that this linear combination will behave as a Coulombic point charge is dead wrong.

Comment: Ok, but I am imagining a parallel plate as the summation over many of these charges? does this relationship break down because the dependence on r changes?

Comment: @DDleo See expanded answer.